# Shell script that creates a file with wc

Tags: bash, shell

I have to write a shell script that puts a file in the directory of the user (the user is put in the parameter), this file contains information about the files passed on in the parameters.

if option -c is present, it creates a file named count that contains the numbers of lines, words and characters of the files passed in parameters.

if option -d is present. it erases the file named count in the directories  passed in the parameters. We suppose that the directories passed in parameters are in a directory on which the shell script has the necessary permissions

This is what I've got so far but it ain't working yet

```
#!/bin/bash

while test $# -gt 0; do
    case "$1" in
                -c)
                    cd $HOME && wc * > count
                    ;;
                -d)
                    cd $HOME && rm -f count
                    ;;
            *)
                    break
                    ;;
    esac
```

done

Comment: so what is your problem/question? Good luck!

Comment: You said that the username and files are passed as parameters. Where are you using those parameters?

Comment: Sorry haven't been clear about my question, any tips to make it better or any obvious mistakes you can see here that i should work on? 

It's for an assignment and my Ubuntu that I run on VMWare crashed since the moment I tried to login as root (but that's another story). So I can't really test it out for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

`$#` never decreases, since you never use `shift` to reduce the number of positional parameters. Your loop just processes the first argument repeated.

```
#!/bin/bash

while test $# -gt 0; do
    case "$1" in
                -c)
                    cd $HOME && wc * > count
                    ;;
                -d)
                    cd $HOME && rm -f count
                    ;;
            *)
                    break
                    ;;
    esac

    shift   # Use this to modify $#

done
```